# Component doesn't receive props

Tags: reactjs

In my **home** component I read a user's name and then I check if it's valid (axios returns an user if the name is correct). If it is valid and I click the button I want to display **Dashboard** component. The problem is even if the name is valid Dashboard **doesn't receive the props** from **Home** component. I tried something with componentDidUpdate but it didn't worked very well. What I don't understand is why if I type a correct user my Dashboard gets rendered but it doesn't get the props?

This is my Home component without constructor:

```
inputChange(event) {
    this.setState({username:event.target.value});
}

login() {
    this.setState({clicked: true})
    UsersService.validUser(this.state.username).then((user) => {
        this.setState({valid: true, user: user})
    });
}

change() {
    this.setState({clicked: false})
}

render() {
    if(this.state.clicked) {
        if (this.state.valid)
            return (
                <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/dashboard', state: { user: this.state.user } }}/>
            )
        else
            this.change;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this)}/>
            <button onClick={this.login}>LOGIN</button>
        </div>
}
```

**Dashboard** component

```
export interface DashboardProps {
    user: IUser
}

interface DashboardState {
}

class Dashboard extends React.Component<DashboardProps, DashboardState> {
    public static defaultProps: DashboardProps = {
        user: {
            userId: '',
            name: '',
            phone: '',
            email: '',
            age: '',
            tag: []
        }
    }
    constructor(props: DashboardProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header user={this.props.user}/>
                <div>
                    <span>Hi, {this.props.user.name}</span> <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `withRouter` HOC of `react-router` in your dashboard component, the current routing props get injected to components.

```
export default withRouter(Dashboard);
```

Edit:

Your state information will be available at `this.props.location.state.user`.

Comment: @zeudarius - Can you add `Dashboard` component in question?

Comment: I've added the dashboard component

Comment: You're answer was correct, I just had to add `type DashboardPropsType = DashboardProps & RouteComponentProps<{}>;` to use props.location Thanks!